# Create Materialized View with Hibernate 4

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, plsql, materialized-views

I create Materialized View with PL/SQL with below code:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW mv_ws_claim_file build immediate
  REFRESH force on demand
          start with trunc(sysdate)
          next (SYSDATE + 7) + 23 / 24 with primary key
  as
  SELECT w.CMPDOCNO
    FROM view_wbsv5 w
   WHERE w.CMPDOCNO NOT IN
         (SELECT wc.claimfilenumber FROM ws_claim_file wc);
```

but I want to create it Materialized View with Hibernate 4 and Mapping it to Entity.

I did not find good resource and solution